# Doob-Meyer decomposition; uniqueness

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a question about the uniqueness of Doob-Meyer decomposition. For the sake of completeness, consider the following form of such a result:

> Let ${\displaystyle Z}$  be a cadlag submartingale of class D. Then there exists a unique, increasing, predictable process ${\displaystyle A}$  with ${\displaystyle A_{0}=0}$  such that ${\displaystyle M_{t}=Z_{t}+A_{t}}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale.

I know that requiring predictability of the FV process $A$ in the decomposition yields a unique decomposition. But, what I do not know is: **do we ever really *need* this uniqueness somewhere?** For example: in results  or in other constructions (of proofs?). Any example is welcome!